# How can I output a list of filenames surrounded by quotation marks?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, dir

In Windows Command Prompt, I can use the **dir** command to output the names of all PNG files within a directory:

```
dir *.png /od /b > files.txt
```

```
file 1.png
file 2.png
...
```

However, the image files I am working with contain **spaces** in their filenames, and hence will not work with ImageMagick unless I surround their names with **quotation marks**, like so:

```
"file 1.png"
"file 2.png"
...
```

What is the best way to go about this?

Is there a command that lists filenames surrounded by quotes?

Or will I need to add them in after creating the txt file?

Comment: [`where /F ".:*.png"`](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html)?

Comment: @aschipfl - Thanks, but I need the files in sequential order. 

This command will output: "file 1", "file 11", "file 12", etc.

I used /od to order by date and get around this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `FOR /F` to run the `DIR` command and surround the output with quotes:

This is from the prompt

```
for /f "delims=" %A in ('dir /b /od *.png') do @echo "%A"
```

In a batch script, you would double the percent signs, so `%A` becomes `%%A` in both places.

Answer (score 4):

A way using PowerShell:

```
(dir *.png | sort creationTime | % {"`"$($_.name)`""}) >>files.txt
```

- Filter `*.png` using `Get-ChildItem`.
- Sort them by `CreationTime`.
- Add double quotes to their names using `Foreach` loop
- Then write them to `files.txt` using operator.